tax liabilities on creation of a discretionary trust
If a person's will bequeaths some money to a discretionary trust fund for the benefit of a list of beneficiaries, does the amount bequeathed to the trust immediately count as trust income subject to income tax (at 45%)?
Assume no money is yet paid out to beneficiaries by the fund and no interest etc has yet been earned from the money.

I don't think that's how it works.  According to this article on taxation of discretionary trusts (my emphasis):

IHT on creation of trust
Lifetime gifts into discretionary trusts are chargeable lifetime
transfers (CLTs).  IHT will be charged at the lifetime rate of  20% on
the amount above the settlor’s nil rate band. There is no 20%
lifetime tax on discretionary will trusts as the estate pays the IHT
at  the death rate of 40% on amounts in excess of the available nil
rate band.

As can be learned from perusing the rest of that article, taxation of trusts is a monstrously complicated specialist subject and preconceived ideas bought from the fields of personal or company tax law can often be unhelpful.
